# How to reset geometry hints made with gtk_window_set_geometry_hints

Tags: gtk

After setting e.g. `max_height`, `max_width` with `gtk_window_set_geometry_hints`, how can they be cleared?

Answer (score -1):

See [GdkGeometry](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkGeometry) documentation:

> the min_width/min_height/max_width/max_height fields may be set to -1,
>   and GtkWindow will substitute the size request of the window or
>   geometry widget

Comment: Thanks, but setting min/max (or just max) to -1 simply causes the window to disappear for me. I'm also confused by the documentation "GtkWindow will substitute the size request of the window..." - that doesn't seem related to removing the hints.

Comment: Window disappearing sounds weird and not what I expected at all. But on second read you're right that the quote isn't really a good answer for your exact question, sorry about that.